# live video in "picture-in-picture" in samsung tv

Tags: video-streaming, samsung-smart-tv, confusion-matrix

I am trying to find my way through the infinite number of sdk's samsung publishes.. and already got a headache ;)

I wish to open a video stream in a samsung smart tv. This can be flash/html, and a new request from a client is that it would start in a PIP (picture-in-picture) screen.

Now, I did see that wonderful picture-in-picture video with the CEO demonstrating it, but I just could not find the API to do that... Is that Multiscreen SDK? AllShare? Web API? SEF API? FLASH? HTML5? which API? ???

Samsung DForum site must have a very busy server...

Answer (score 0):

Samsung TV until 2013 products cannot play 2 media sources at the same time. So you may see either marketing promotional videos or hopefully new feature of the new products

Comment: Are you sure? Because samsung do say that their multiscreen sdk has this option.  not that I found it...

Comment: yeah that's why i said "hopefully new feature of the new products" because i've tried the multiscreen sdk on 2013 TV and it's still not supported, maybe waiting for firmware update or something else

Comment: I did find however a "pip" button on the web browser. It does nothing when pressed, but thats probably because theres no real stream connected

Comment: I am also seeking for this option, couldn't find how to develop an app with it. However I did see the PIP option in Samsung's SmartTV 2013 and 2014 menu - Go to menu --> picture --> PIP. I would appreciate the help if anyone found a way...